# Intellij - indentation when copying multiple lines

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

I have a class `Foo`

```
public class Foo {
    String property1;
    int property2;
    Object property3;
    List<String> property4;
}
```

[image: Selected properties from Foo]

Now I would like to copy the names of the properties to class `Bar`.

```
public class Bar {
    property1
    property2
    property3
    property4
}
```

Obviously, this code does not compile, but the goal is to call a template to generate some code. When copying valid Java code, there is no problem. Unfortunately, probably because this code does not compile, when copying the selected properties from `Foo` in a Java source File, the indentation of class `Bar` is not like this, but:

```
public class Bar {

    property1
            property2
    property3
            property4
}
```

[image: copied properties to Baar]

Is there a way to get those properties in one column in a Java File?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the templates you want to call simply insert the type before a field.
In that case you could:

1. use <kbd>F2</kbd> to navigate through each error
2. fill in the type
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> ("Complete current statement" action) to add the missing semicolon and properly indent the line

Or you could also:

1. select the copied property names
2. unindent them all the way (now they are aligned)
3. reindent them

Comment: The template could do different things, it could also be in methods and so on. Actually, I am currently already using the unident-reindent solution, but maybe there is another solution...

Comment: @user140547, you could also copy the properties with types and replace them as needed (or remove them in bulk).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which seems to be an improvement over the current way.

It is possible to do a ["Paste Simple"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html#d1656357e328) in Intellij using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This way, Intellij does no-auto formatting. So when the cursor is at the start of the line, a block is inserted.

[image: Bar with paste simple]

After that, it is possible to call the templates and only when having valid Java Code, I can call <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reformat the code.